# Cannot see other devices on the network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking

I am not the administrator of the access point I connect to, but for some reason, other devices don't see each other. For example, my phone is at `10.0.0.4` and my Debian at `10.0.0.7`, I cannot `arp -a` to see each other, and I cannot ping either device from either device successfully. I can only scan for the gateway address, and the administrator's device at `10.0.0.1`.

What could be the reason behind such behaviour? Could it perhaps be some router option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wireless isolation is turned on, as is typical for guest wifi connections. If you'd like not to have that, get your own internet connection, router and access point, and then you can set the options as you like them.